# What are some effective methods to fix a worn out screw holes of a door hinge?

Tags: doors, screws, hinges, hole-repair

I have a door that was slightly tilted and didnt close properly. I noticed the hinge was a tad loose, and what was holding it was a short 0.5" screw. I replaced it the screws with a new 1" screw and the door was ok for a couple weeks. But now its tilting sideways again, and the screws are loose again.

I assume that the screw holes are worn out and thus do not hold the screws well, and gave up.

The door, and the door frame, is a regular standard US wooden door. The hinges are common as well. Not familiar with exact model, type, or naming convention. In the images you can see the hinge tilting sideways, as well as it pushing the screws out from the screwholes.

I was thinking about using screw anchors. But what other methods are there to fix a loose screw hole?

Attached Images
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you

Comment: If the heads allow the door to close all the way, you can try going to the next size up screw.  If what's there now is #10, see if a #12 of the same length will work.

Comment: toothpicks to fill + much longer screws (e.g., 2"). See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20320/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-fix-my-door-hinge

Comment: Images and additional information was added. This is not a duplicate of the damaged door hinge - as I am asking about the hinge's screw holes.

Comment: It is a duplicate of the suggestion by  manassehkatz. That question isn't actually about a broken hinge and all those solutions apply.

Answer (score 1):

I drill the hole out to a standard wood dowel size, then put in a dowel plug and what's called "Swell-Lock", a product that isn't a glue, it gets absorbed into the wood fibers and makes them swell up and lock into the hole (it's generally sold to repair chair rungs, but it works great for this). Then re-drill a pilot hole in the dowel and you are good as new.

Answer (score 0):

Every handyman has his preferred hack, but every method is a hack. Sometimes you can pack the hole with wood putty or wood flooring filler, if the hole is to loose you can slide some wood slivers (matchstickes) into the hole. As much as possible try to let the putty set before putting any torsion on the hinge.